# What am I missing about boost::mpi::request ? Testing seems to change state

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

So I've got this simple MPI example thrown together. I'm seeing some weird behavior around testing boost::mpi::request that I can't explain. Specifically, if you remove the commenting on the second loop, it spins forever. Does test on a boost::mpi::request only return true once? If so, what bit of state is getting updated? I've poked through Boost's MPI and optional code and I can't explain what I'm seeing.

(naturally, for the uninitiated, you'll need to use mpiexec with two nodes to run this yourself.)

```
# include "stdafx.h"
# include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
# include <boost/mpi.hpp>
# include <windows.h>
# include <iostream>
# include <boost/mpi.hpp>
# include <boost/optional.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    boost::mpi::environment m_env;
    boost::mpi::communicator m_world;

    if (m_world.rank() == 0)
    {
        m_world.send(1,0, std::string("hi!"));
    }
    else
    {

        std::shared_ptr<std::string> rcv = std::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string());
        boost::mpi::request x = m_world.irecv(0, 0, *rcv);
        while (!x.test())
        {
            Sleep(10);
        }
        //while (!x.test())
        //{
        //  Sleep(10);
        //}
        std::cout << *rcv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation, sort of:

```
  /**
   *  Determine whether the communication associated with this request
   *  has completed successfully. If so, returns the @c status object
   *  describing the communication. Otherwise, returns an empty @c
   *  optional<> to indicate that the communication has not completed
   *  yet. Note that once @c test() returns a @c status object, the
   *  request has completed and @c wait() should not be called.
   */
  optional<status> test();
```

Then look at the [docs for the underlying MPI_Test function](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Test.html):

> A call to MPI_TEST returns flag = true if the operation identified by request is complete. In such a case, the status object is set to contain information on the completed operation; if the communication object was created by a nonblocking send or receive, then it is deallocated and the request handle is set to MPI_REQUEST_NULL.
>
> One is allowed to call MPI_TEST with a null or inactive request argument. In such a case the operation returns with flag = true and empty status.

So what we see is that Boost MPI's `test()` method returns an `optional<status>`, and `MPI_Test()` can only return a status once (after that, the request is destroyed).  `MPI_Test()` called repeatedly would return `flag = true`, but that's not what you're checking.  If you really need this pattern, you could probably call `MPI_Test()` yourself and use the returned flag instead of status.  Or just do the bookkeeping in your application, and don't call `boost::mpi::request::test()` twice on the same request.

Another way to look at this problem is that you are using the result of `test()` in a boolean context, where you expect it to work like the `flag` of `MPI_Test()`, but actually it works like the `status`, and its bool nature is only an illusion.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing - just bookkeping my own bool. I didn't consider the underlying MPI_TEST - thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is consistent with the MPI standard. When [MPI_TEST](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node64.htm#Node64) indicates the operation has completed, the returned status object will contain the information about the completed operation, and the operation object itself is marked inactive or de-allocated (whichever applies). Calling MPI_TEST again on that operation object would return an empty status.

The (latest version of the) MPI standard provides a way to access the status in a non-destructive way : [MPI_REQUEST_GET_STATUS](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node67.htm#Node67).

I'm not aware of an implementation of this operation in boost, but you can just store the returned `status` object, and refer to that later instead of calling `test` again.